# When meteor user logged in Iron Router will not route Router.current().params.username to different profile

Tags: meteor, iron-router

When meteor user is logged out, I can visit www.foo.com/usernameA and this will bring up the usernameA page with all of the profile info . When I do this for www.foo.com/usernameB the same thing occurs. All of this works great. When I log into the meteor accounts with a user and attempt to enter the same addresses to the usernames, I continually get routed to the currently logged in users profile page. The currently logged in user keeps hijacking the Router.current().params.username and always making that the current parameter.

Here is the basics of my code:

routes.js

```
Router.route('/:username', {
template: 'userPubProfile',
onBeforeAction: function(){
var profileUserExists = Meteor.users.find({"profile.user-url" :   
Router.current().params.username}).count();

  if (profileUserExists == 0) {
    this.render('404');
  }
  else {
    this.next();
  }
 }
});
```

userPubProfile.js

```
Template.userPubProfile.helpers({
  'userFirstName' : function(){
    var getUser = Meteor.users.findOne({"profile.user-url" :  
Router.current().params.username});
return getUser.profile['first-name'];
 }
});
```

My question:
How do I make the routing work the same when the user is logged in or logged out when attempting to connect to router using the /:username parameter?

Comment: try `console.log` in your helper before returning and observe what are you getting.

Comment: I did the console.log. The problem is.... When the meteor user is logged in whatever url i enter automatically gets re-directed to the username that is logged in.  For example: If i am logged in and the users profile is www.website.com/john , and I then type in www.website.com/bob.... The router is automatically re-directing the bob to www.website.com/john... Why is it redirecting when logged in?

Answer (score 2):

I want to thank everyone. I was able to fix the issue. This was due to an old line that I had inserted prior to building out my /:username route to collect the username router parameter. I ended up discovering that inside my Accounts.onLogin() I had a call that was doing...

```
var getUserUrl = Meteor.user().profile['user-url'];
    Router.go('/' + getUserUrl);
```

I had to simply remove these lines and now everything is correct! Thanks!